# Browser Manual refreshing showing JSON data in webpage using angular js routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider,$routeParams){$routeProvider.when('/mainpage',{templateUrl :'/views/index.html',controller :'mainpage'})
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have in "mainpage" controller and index.html?

Comment: var refreshMD=function()
 {
  $http.get('/support').success(function(response)
  {
   // $scope.curdate = new Date('2014-11-19');
   console.log("MD UPDATED DATA"+response);
   $scope.support=response;


  });
 };

 refreshMD();

Comment: Update it in the question not in comment and also show HTML page and whole controller code as well.. only then we can help... Code  you provided right now is not enough..